# Gremlin - run additional traversal in same query in case not enough values are found

Tags: gremlin

Is there a way to check how many records were found, and in case less than X records were returned do another query?

For example first run this query ->

```
g.V().
  hasLabel('courseContent').
  has('status', 'active').as('cc').
  outE('ccBelongsToCourse').
  has('status', 'active').
  inV().
  hasLabel('course').
  has('externalId', ':courseId').
  select('cc').by(valueMap('externalId')).
  dedup().
  range(:offSet, :limit);
```

And in case less than 10 records were found, run this query:

```
g.V().
  hasLabel('educatorContent').
  has('status', 'active').as('ec').
  select('ec').by(valueMap('externalId')).
  dedup().
  range(:offSet, :limit);
```

but do it all inside the same `.gremlin` file?

(Sorry if the question is too basic, super new to Gremlin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `choose()` which provides if-then semantics:

```
range(:offSet, :limit).fold().
choose(count(local).is(gt(9)),
       identity(),
       V().has('educatorContent', 'status','active')....)
```

Comment: I cannot set limit values for `range`? Because I would like to avoid cases where more than 10 items are retuned from the first query

Comment: i fixed my code example slightly - forgot to do a `local` for `count()`. i don't follow your question though - i shorthanded that query a bit and removed your arguments to `range()` perhaps, that was the confusion?

Comment: all good, its clear, thanks

Comment: I get an error that the query is malformed, can you please advise? `g.V(). hasLabel('courseContent'). has('status', 'active').as('ec'). outE('ccBelongsToCourse'). has('status', 'active'). inV(). hasLabel('school').order().by(shuffle). has('externalId', ':courseId'). has('status', 'active'). select('ec').by(valueMap('externalId')). dedup(). range(:offSet, :limit). fold(). choose(count(local).is(lt(4)), identity(), V().hasLabel('courseContent'). has('status', 'active').as('ec'). select('ec').by(valueMap('externalId')). dedup(). range(:offSet, :limit));`

Comment: i copy/pasted that to Gremlify/Gremlint and don't see anything wrong with it. Gremlfy actually runs it and returns 0 results which makes sense. I only had to get rid of your variables for offset/limit and it worked. usually "malformed" errors will specify the line/location of the failure - did it do that? also, what graph database are you using?